# Deserialization of Untrusted Data

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

In a security run on our code base we are getting a high priority issue i.e. "**Deserialization of Untrusted Data**" We are using Newtonsoft JSON package for deserialization. Below is the code snippet used and I followed this stack overflow answer([Fixing the deserializing of untrusted data using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993669/fixing-the-deserializing-of-untrusted-data-using-c-sharp)) to solve this issue. It is still not resolved. Any pointers will be helpful.

```
var idstate = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[Constants.State];
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();                             
LoginRedirection redirectionObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginRedirectionModel>(idstate, jsonSerializerSettings)?.ToLoginRedirection();
```

**Models used for deserialization are below**:-

```
public class LoginRedirection                                                                        
{
   public string stateUrl { get; set; }
   public string cartSession { get; set; }                                                           
}

public class LoginRedirectionModel                                                                   
{
  public string stateUrl { get; set; }
  public string cartSession { get; set; }

  public LoginRedirection ToLoginRedirection()
  {
    return new LoginRedirection { stateUrl = stateUrl, cartSession = cartSession };
  }                                                                                                  
}
```

Security exception "OWASP Top 10 2017: A8-Insecure Deserialization" is coming for the below line

```
LoginRedirection redirectionObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginRedirectionModel>(idstate, jsonSerializerSettings)?.ToLoginRedirection();
```

JSON:-

```
{ "stateUrl"="<URL HERE>", "cartSession":"<GUID HERE>"}
```

Another aspect to problem is:-
When we consume an API using HttpClient and then trying to deserialize the response from API, we are getting the same security warning. Below is the code for consuming and deserializing the API.

```
public T Post<T, M>(M data, string url, bool ocpSubscriptionHeaderRequired = true)
{
  T response = default(T);
  try
  {       
    string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);        

    using (var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApiRequestTimeOutInSeconds) })
    {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      if (ocpSubscriptionHeaderRequired)
      {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove(Constants.ApiSubscriptionKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.ApiSubscriptionKey, GenericUtilities.GetConfigData(Constants.ApiSubscriptionKeyValue));
      }

      HttpResponseMessage result = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))).Result;
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        string responseString = Task.Run(() => result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                                                                           { 
                                                                                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None 
                                                                           });            
      }          
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {        
    _logger.WriteException(ex);        
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: What are you getting exactly (which error), from who (which static analyser) and at which line?

Comment: Which JSON are you deserializing?

Comment: JSON is having only two properties, see the "LoginRedirection" class in my question. Security exception "OWASP Top 10 2017: A8-Insecure Deserialization" this coming for the line LoginRedirection redirectionObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginRedirectionModel>(idstate, jsonSerializerSettings)?.ToLoginRedirection();

Comment: @AlokBhatt add the information to the question itself. Comments are just comments. They can be deleted at any time and code written in a comment is *very* hard to read, unless it's half a line

Comment: @AlokBhatt the answer to the question you linked to is pretty clear too - you have to think what the problem is, what's needed and what can be done to fix it, not just copy some random code. In your case, how come the redirect URL came in a JSON string? Where did this string come from? If it's posted from a login page, could someone rewrite that page's Javascript to replace the redirect URL with something else?

Comment: In fact, I'd ask "why are you creating your own login mechanism"? All ASP.NET stacks provide authentication and login pages out-of-the-box. Your custom code combines *both* login *and* a link to a cart. Could someone hijack someone else's cart this way, by posting someone else's cart session? ASP.NET's login on the other hand (any stack) would display the login page if you tried to access *any* URL that required authentication, then redirect back to it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IdentityProvider is posting some data to my web application which I need to deserialize. So point here is not how I have implemented my login, it is about when deserializing any data posted from third party application, how to avoid this security warning.

Comment: @AlokBhatt if that were the case, all ASP.NET applications would fail those tests. The error is about security, which, in this case, it means it's about authentication and login. If you just want to cover up the warning, you can disable it. Or you can understand what the implications are, why you have that warning in the first place, and fix it. BTW you haven't posted the JSON payload yet

Comment: @AlokBhatt you didn't mention which analyser was used either. It's quite possible the analyser is over-reacting. The example given for [insecure deserialisation](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/Marshaller_Deserialization_Attacks.pdf.pdf) is more complex. On the other hand, you're redirecting the client to whatever is in `stateUrl`, without checking whether it's an absolute or relative URL, or if it belongs to your site or some malicious site

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Postes JSON sample for you. Lets take another example, suppose I am calling a WEB API using HttpClient. I am getting the same security warning for deserialization of API response too. So how can I consume a third party API and deserialize that response without getting this warning.

Comment: @AlokBhatt someone could execute Javascript on the client that posts an absolute `stateUrl` that redirects to a malicious site

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(sourceJsonString, obj)` instead of deserializing it using `JsonConvert.DesrializeObject<>();`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a false-positive to me.

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` with the wrong `JsonSerializerSettings` options *could* be used to construct some other .net type, which *could* execute something unexpected within its constructor. Or you could write your own serialiser, with some other exploitable bugs in it.

But if you can't use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` for a simple object with two string fields, then every .net app that handles json would already be broken.